# Basic inequality involving modulus

Tags: calculus

If $0\leq a,b\leq 1$ and $\lvert a-b\rvert\leq r$ for some $r>0$, then $a\leq b+r$ and $a\geq b-r$?

By definition, they are equivalent.

Comment: What exactly is Your question?

Comment: $|a-b|\leq r\iff -r\leq a-b\leq r$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's think it through.

If $|M| \le r$ then $-r \le -|M| \le 0$.  Now $|M|= \begin{cases}M& M \ge 0\\-M& M < 0\end{cases}$ or in other words $M =\begin{cases}|M| & M \ge 0\\-|M|& M < 0\end{cases}$.

So if $M < 0$ then we have $-r\le M < 0$.  And if $M \ge 0$ then we have $0\le M < r$.  And, in either case, it will be true that $-r < M < r$.  So

> Lemma: $|M|\le r\iff -r \le M \le r$

So we have $|a-b| \le r$.  SO that means $-r \le a-b \le r$.

And so $a-b \le r$ so $a \le r+b$.

And we have $-r \le a-b$ so $b-r \le a$ so $a \ge b-r$.

So, yep, they are both true.

The condition $0 \le a,b \le 1$ is not relevant.  The result would still be true if $a,b$ where *any* real values.

... oh, but I guess to show the statements are equivalent I have to show they go both ways.

If we given $a\le b+r$ and $a \ge b-r$ then we conclude $a-b \le r$ and $a-b \ge -r$ and $-r \ge a-b \le r$.  (Note: we don't need to be *told* $r \ge 0$.  these conditions are not possible if $r < 0$.  Oh but this could hold if $r =0$.)

If $a-b \ge 0$ then $|a-b| = a-b \le r$ and if $a-b < 0$ then $-r \ge a-b = -|a-b|$ and so $|a-b| \le r$.

So yep,

> For any $a,b \in \mathbb R$ and for some $r \ge 0$ then:   $|a-b| \le r \iff a\le b+r$ and $a\ge b-r$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\forall a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ also $\forall r>0$ we can write this,
$$|X|\leq r \implies -r \leq X \leq r$$so you can rewrite $$\forall a,b \  \in [0,1]: |a-b|\leq r \Leftrightarrow-r\leq a-b\leq r\\ \text{all sides } +b\\
b-r\leq a-b+b\leq b+r\\b-r \leq a\leq b+r$$ or if you have different definition for absolute sign like $\ |x|=\max \{x,-x\}$ you can also do like this
$$\max \{a-b,b-a\}\leq r \\\to 
\begin{cases}a-b\leq r & \implies a\leq b+r \\b-a\leq r & \implies b-r\leq a \end{cases}$$ hope it can helps you